# Filter the dataframe based on Date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe like below :

```
    |  Date    |  Value |
    +----------+--------+
    |2009-01-01|  34    |
    |2009-01-03|  45    |
    |2009-02-03|  56    |
    |2009-02-18|  57    |
    |2009-03-17|  59    |
    |2009-03-26|  60    |
    |2010-01-01|  23    |
    |2010-01-17|  34    |
    |2010-02-14|  23    |
    |2010-02-18|  42    |
    |2010-03-21|  12    |
    |2010-03-29|  11    |
    +----------+--------+
```

I want to filter the data frame to include values of only January month and not other months, which should like below.

```
    |  Date    |  Value |
    +----------+--------+
    |2009-01-01|  34    |
    |2009-01-03|  45    |
    |2010-01-01|  23    |
    |2010-01-17|  34    |
    +----------+--------+
```

So, how to filter such dataframes using date column ? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the date into datetime type with

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

then use `dt.month`:

```
df[df['Date'].dt.month==1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iff the pattern is fixed, a way is to check 5th and 6th characters:

```
df[df.Date.str[5:7] == "01"]
```

to get

```
         Date  Value
1  2009-01-01   34.0
2  2009-01-03   45.0
7  2010-01-01   23.0
8  2010-01-17   34.0
```